# How to check whether time limit already exist in table?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

I have many records in `mongodb` database in table **academicyearTbl** like

```
 "_id": ObjectId("5a3b41581d78593809000029"),
 "academicyear_id": 67,
  "academicyearname": "2017",
  "startson"▼: "01/01/2017",
  "endson": "12/31/2017",
  "graceperiod": "12/14/2017",
 "status": "active",
```

I am trying to tweak the below code

**code:**

```
      class settingsModel
      {
      function testcode()
      {
      $this->collection = $this->db->academicyearTbl;
      $query4 = array('startson'=> $this->startson,'endson' => $this->endson);
      $count4 = $this->collection->find($query4)->count();
      if($count4 > 0)
      {
        //show message
      }
      else
      {
         // allow inserting the new record
      }
      }
      }
      $foo = new settingsModel();
      $foo->academicyearname ="2018"
      $foo->startson="06/02/2017";
      $foo->endson="12/01/2017";
      $foo->testcode();
```

I am very new to `mongodb`, I am able to get any inspiration for comparing whether 
new start and end dates being entered should not fall in the already existing  time period in the database.

For e.g 
if user will enter new data like

```
      $foo->academicyearname ="2018"
      $foo->startson="06/02/2017";
      $foo->endson="12/01/2017";
```

Then it should not be allowed to get inserted because there is already data in the table as mentioned in the first.

Please help !!!

Answer (score 0):

You should set the two dates as `\DateTimeImmutable`  and then you can use the `$gt` and `$lt` operators for the `MongoDate` (which is obsolete) when checking the interval, like this:

```
class settingsModel
{
    function testcode()
    {
      $this->collection = $this->db->academicyearTbl;

      $query4 = array(
         'startson'=> array( 
            '$gt' => new MongoDate( $this->startson ),
         ),
         'endson' =>  array( 
            '$lt' => new MongoDate( $this->endson ),
         ),
      );

      $count4 = $this->collection->find($query4)->count();
      if($count4 > 0)
      {
        //show message
      }
      else
      {
         // allow inserting the new record
      }
  }
} 

$foo = new settingsModel();
$foo->academicyearname ="2018";
$foo->startson = strtotime("2017-02-06"); //notice the date format
$foo->endson = strtotime("2017-01-12"); //notice the date format
$foo->testcode();
```

P.S. your code needs a lot of other refactorings

Comment: Thanks for the answer... u mean i have to convert date to timestamp like

Comment: $mongosd = new MongoDate(strtotime($this->startson)); 
          $mongoed = new MongoDate(strtotime($this->endson));

Comment: You need to have `\MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime` for the dates inserted in MongoDB

Comment: Yes, you need to somehow (by using timestamps or `\DateTimeImmutable`) generate `\MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime` and store that in the database

Comment: I don't know what version of mongodb you are using; use whatever types you have available on your system

Comment: i am using 3.2 version

Comment: I mean what version of php extension; I think you are using http://php.net/manual/ro/book.mongo.php which is deprecated

Comment: It is throwing error syntax error, unexpected ')'  at line   'startson'=> array( 
            '$gt' => new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime( $this->startson->setTime(0,0,0 ),
         ),

Comment: no issues... it is throwing error message Class 'MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime' not found

Comment: then use `MongoDate` instead of `\MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime`

Comment: if i use '$gt' => new MongoDate($this->startson), it throws error message A non well formed numeric value encountered i

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161688/discussion-between-constantin-galbenu-and-nida-amin).